# Weird Method HtmlHelper::input does not exist

Tags: cakephp

i don't know what to do i'm confuse because i'm new in cakephp world can somebody help me?

here's the code of the helper.php line 179

```
trigger_error(__d('cake_dev', 'Method %1$s::%2$s does not exist', get_class($this), $method), E_USER_WARNING);
```

this is my add.ctp

```
    <h1>Add Inventory</h1>    
<form action="<?php echo $this->Html->url("/Stocks/add"); ?>" method="post">    

    <p>    
        ProductName:      
        <?php echo $this->Html->input('Stock/ProductName', array('size' => '40'))?>    
    </p>    
    <p>    
        Price:      
        <?php echo $this->Html->integers('Stock/Price', array('size' => '10'))?>    
    </p>    
<p>
   Quantity:
   <?php echo $this->Html->integers('Stock/Quantity', array('size' => '5'))?>
</p>
    <p>    
        <?php echo $this->Html->submit('Save') ?>    
    </p>    
</form>
```

help --,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$this->Html->input
```

should be

```
$this->Form->input
```

**since its FormHelper function not HtmlHelper**

Comment: @Ying: If this answer solved your problem, you should reward the answerer by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: @Li-aungYip ok, done. i'm just new here. now can you please answer my new question?

Comment: @Ying: Unfortunately, I don't know PHP or CakePHP. So that's a "no, I can't answer your question." :)

Comment: you just scolded me . ok i'll just wait someone to answer. thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, the [HtmlHelper does not have an `input` method](http://api.cakephp.org/class/html-helper).
Looks like you're looking for the [FormHelper](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper) instead.